# setTimeout not working in SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, mozilla, spidermonkey

I have built spidermonkey on mac by following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation). Under build-release/dist/bin the executable is js24 instead of js ( accoring to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell) ).

However, when I run the shell using js24, expressions like 1+2 is working, but when I try things like setTimeout(function () {}, 500) I am getting,

```
ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong ? I thought the behaviour would be same as the node shell.

Comment: `setTimeout` is not part of the language.

Comment: `setTimeout` is a function of the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) object which is your global in your browser. No `window`, no `setTimeout`

Comment: @MattBurland got it, thanks. Does v8 too behaves this way and node adds this ?

Comment: First result for "spidermonkey settimeout": https://gist.github.com/kevinoid/3146420

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving the excellent answers from the comments as an actual answer, so that this question can be marked as answered.

setTimeout is not part of the JavaScript language, it's part of the browser's `window` object, which is the global object for a web page's JavaScript code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout

node.js has a similar API: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg

To implement setTimeout in SpiderMonkey you can use this code:
https://gist.github.com/kevinoid/3146420